# Azure Python webjob only working if I run it from Kudu

Tags: python, azure, azure-webjobs

I created an Azure webjob using Python, and when I first ran it, it did not work because it could not find the modules. So I created a requirements.txt file and included it in the zip file when I uploaded it, and then I went into Kudu and found the directory where Python.exe existed and ran:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade -r D:\home\site\wwwroot\....directory...\requirements.txt
```

So it installed the modules correctly, and when I ran from Kudu:

```
Python D:\home\site\wwwroot\....directory...\my_file.py
```

It worked. However, if I go back to the Portal and tell the web job to run that way, it still says it can't find those libraries. What's the issue?

Comment: Not sure it will help, but try including a `run.cmd` in your WebJob and have that run the right Python command line. If that doesn't work, you may need to share a test Web App name for investigation.

Comment: Thanks... I tried that and it didn't work, unless I put it in the wrong directory? I put the run.cmd file in this directory: D:\home\Python364x64

Comment: It needs to be part of your WebJobs files. See [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have installed the extension for python3.6.

Then in your run.cmd file, you should add this line of code: `D:\home\python364x64\python.exe my_file.py`, then put your run.cmd and the my_file.py in the same .zip file.

Upload it to webjob and install required libraries as you did before.

I have tested on my side, it works.